# Detect/Prevent Floating Apps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, overlay, kiosk, locked

I wan't to prevent Floating Apps in my App because i created an exam app. I want to implement if the user can't open any browser. i already implement the kiosk mode for locked the user in the app but it is not enough because the user can still open the floating apps on their phone.
[image][image][image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I added a picture of the floating/overlay apps that i wan't to prevent/detect/blocked. I hope that help you to understand the problem. If you have clue or something for this problem please tell me. Thanks